# How to modify fixed title in push notification project?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to modify my project so I can send a push notification with title and message, I can only send a notification message from my web server and the title `Elt` as you can see from the code below is fixed.

**Firebasemessagingservice.java**:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}



private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Elt")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea. When you send the message just make the first WORD as the Title, and then split it.

```
//example message= "MYTITLE This is my message";
String arr[] = message.split(" ", 2);
String title= arr[0];   //MYTITLE 
String message1 = arr[1];     //This is my message
```

See below for complete code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}



private void showNotification(String message) {

     //example message= "MYTITLE This is my message";
    String arr[] = message.split(" ", 2);
    String title= arr[0];   //MYTITLE 
    String message1 = arr[1];     //This is my message

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)  //here the title
            .setContentText(message1)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
```